# Accounting for multiple autoconf versions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autoconf

I have 3 programs, two of which require an older version of autoconf one of which requires a newer version. right now all three programs are calling the newest autoconf version. I believe I have to modify the path to autoconf in the makefiles of the first two programs to resolve the issue, but it could very well be aclocal.m4 or configure.ac for that matter.

Which file in gnu-make calls autoconf? Where and in what syntax is the path defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in make should have to call `autoconf`, unless (in some cases) you edit `configure.ac`. You execute `autoconf` yourself (either directly, or indirectly from `autoreconf`) to generate the `configure` script from `configure.ac`.

Some programs also include a script called `autogen.sh` or `bootstrap` that calls `autoconf`. This should only be needed when checking the program out from source control.

Note that if you just want to compile the program and you don't edit `configure.ac`, you don't even need to have `autoconf` installed.

My advice is, if you need to edit `configure.ac`, then manually call the required version of `autoconf` after you edit it. Or consider upgrading `configure.ac` to use the latest version. I'm sure the author of the original program will thank you for it.

Comment: Also, if the program truly does have autoconf as a dependency, please report it as a packaging bug to the maintainer and ask them for a correctly built distribution tarball.

Comment: Just as you said, it was configure.ac that was being modified. Oddly enough however, the makefile was calling "autoheader configure.ac". How this ended up calling autoconf is beyond me, but manually referencing the correct autoconf version by appending to PATH within the command resolved the build issue.